# Trigger points in Code coverage using GNU libs GCOV, LCOV for SystemC?

Tags: triggers, code-coverage, gcov, systemc, lcov

I am using GNU Libs GCOV, and LCOV in SystemC for code coverage analysis.
Everything works fine, but I was wondering if it's possible to have trigger points? just like oscilloscope has a trigger option, which captures the state at the trigger point. I want to capture the coverage report at that particular instance, more like a footprint if that's the right term.

Or if it's not possible, is it possible to have a coverage report at a particular time instance?

Thanks.